# Why can't the Java 7 and Eclipse 3.8 compiler compile JDK code with the new Java 7 diamond operator?

Tags: java, generics, java-7, diamond-operator

```
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleArrays
{
  @SafeVarargs
  public static <T> List<T> asList( T... a )
  {
    return new ArrayList<>( a );
  }
}
```

`asList()` is taken from Oracles JDK implementation of java.util.Arrays.

The error is

```
error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>
    return new ArrayList<>( a );
1 error
```

How can this work? Oracle uses the same compiler that we do.

Comment: Have you compiled this using `javac`? Please show your compilation command and the output of `javac -version`.

Comment: I have the same error in NetBeans.  However, if I try it by hand with javac, it does compile.

Comment: the rule of thumb is: if you think you found a bug in java with three lines of code, you're probably doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Attention:** The `ArrayList` used in the `java.util.Arrays` class is not `java.util.ArrayList`, but a nested class `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`.

In particular, this class has an constructor which takes a `T[]` as argument, which `java.util.ArrayList` does not have.

Copy this class, too, and it will work.

Comment: I still wonder why they chose such a confusing name for the array wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can gather, Eclipse wants to find a specific type to infer into the templated `ArrayList`. For example, if your method's signature was:

```
public static List<Integer> asList( Integer... a )
```

Eclipse would have no problem inferring the type of `ArrayList<>( a )`, and would infer that its type is `Integer`. I believe the diamond operator is meant to operate that way: to infer a *specific* type, not a templated one.

Fortunately, you have templated the entire method, so that you could form your statement thus:

```
      return new ArrayList<T>( a );
```

And everything would work :).

Comment: Please read carefuly: "How can this work? Oracle uses the same compiler that we do." The source is original from the JDK as I wrote "is taken from Oracles JDK implementation of java.util.Arrays".

Comment: Sorry, this answer is incorrect. The code in the OP is perfectly legal.